# Select value in table if it exists in another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all the values from a users table where a specific company name is found.
I also need to get the rows in the users table where that same company name is in another table and matches the name in users table

I have 2 tables like this:

Table: Users.

```
   USERNAME COMPANY EMAIL PHONE
```

Table: Dispatchers.

```
   USERNAME DISPATCH_CLIENT
```

I need to get all the rows in the Users table that have a specific company name

I also need to get all the rows in the Users table where the USERNAME and DISPATCH_CLIENT fields in the Dispatch table match the USERNAME AND COMPANY field in Users table.

I have looked at some questions on here using EXISTS, but it either didn't work in my situation or i'm not smart enough to understand it.

This is what I have at the moment.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.COMPANY = '" . $company . "'
    AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT USERNAME
        FROM Dispatchers WHERE DISPATCH_CLIENT = '" . $company . "')";
```

Also tried doing it this way but no records are returned:

```
SELECT 
        *
        FROM 
        Users
        INNER JOIN
        Dispatchers
        ON Dispatchers.USERNAME = Users.USERNAME
        AND Dispatchers.DISPATCH_CLIENT = Users.COMPANY
        WHERE 
        Users.COMPANY = '" . $company . "'"
```

Comment: DISPATCH_CLIENT  or client_company?

Comment: oops DISPATCH_CLIENT, I'll edit it to fix

Comment: do you have sample data?

Comment: It's not data that I can post on a public web site, unfortunately. I may just have to create 2 queries and dump the data into arrays, then compare the 2 arrays. Cumbersome, but it will work in a pinch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.COMPANY = '" . $company . "'
    OR Users.USERNAME IN
    (SELECT USERNAME
        FROM Dispatchers WHERE DISPATCH_CLIENT = '" . $company . "')";
```

Comment: It's not returning any results. I think it's because of the AND statement. I need all of the records in the users table that match that company, even if there is no user match in the Dispatchers table

Comment: changing the AND to an OR gave the results I needed. Thank you for this, i'm marking your answer as the final answer

Comment: @user3101337 It was my pleasure to help you. I'll edit that in the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the join condition in "exists" phase. Please try this.

```sql
SELECT * 
    FROM Users
    WHERE Users.COMPANY = '" . $company . "'
    AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT USERNAME
        FROM Dispatchers 
        WHERE Dispatchers.DISPATCH_CLIENT = Users.COMPANY 
             and Users.USERNAME = Dispatchers.USERNAME)
```